# C++ Epoch to Timestamp

Tags: c++

Essentially I am looping through a sqlite table getting the relevant data that I need to present, including that of a timestamp which is stored in Epoch like so '1409827517628'. All I wish to do is convert that integer into a string with the format of '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a 'write this code for me' site. `stringstream` it...

Comment: UNIX timestamp 1409827517628 is in the distant, distant, distant future.

Comment: You mean  Thu, 04 Sep 2014 10:45:17 GMT ... yeah distant future.

Comment: @Stoodent: `date --date='@1409827517628'` gives Thu Aug 28 04:53:48 MEST 46645 which *is* in the distant future

Comment: so explain to me where I'm getting Thu, 04 Sep 2014 10:45:17 GMT from.

Comment: I'll explain it for you. It's stored in Milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the C functions [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) to convert a `time_t` (which generally is some integral type) to a `struct tm` then use [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) to convert it to a C string, e.g.:

```
time_t yourtime = something(); // from database perhaps
char yourbuf[64];
strftime(yourbuf, sizeof(yourbuf), 
         "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
         localtime(&yourtime));
std::string yourstring(yourbuf);
```

Beware, code above is not re-entrant so not suitable for multi-threaded applications (in that case, use `localtime_r` etc...)

If you need the opposite conversion (from a string to a `time_t`), use [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) then [mktime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) ....

With C++11, use also [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It originally wasn't. I've removed my downvote and upvoted the answer. :-)